# Hawkman and an imprisoned green lantern? (animated series)

Tags: comics, green-lantern-tas

While it might have been explained while my 2 year old was jumping on me during the episode, I must have missed it?

In a recent episode of Green Lantern: TAS Hal and Kilawog travel back to a prison asteroid in search of an imprisoned Lantern (whom they miraculously remember being there) hoping to find out a password. Eventually running into (I'm guessing?) Hawkman Kator Hol; who, in exchange for his help, wants the dead Lantern's power ring, although its long lost its charge and is useless.

I'm wondering if this follows any comic arc, or what the reason for the incarceration of a Lantern was? Seeing as he was a champion of justice, even though no one thought of taking his power ring from him (wouldn't there be a sector without a champion now?)

Secondly why would Hawkman want a dead power ring so badly? Even if it had a charge I did not think he would be able to put it on?

Sorry for massive ramble, first time user.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

He is not Kator Hol.

He is Thanagarian thief 'Byth Rok.' (And he is the villan of the Hawkman.)

Byth like stealing and collecting just for the thrill of the adventure.